# Call a method just before OnClick is called

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclick

I have been looking for my question on Google and inside the forum but I cannot an answer so far. I am using android studio to code an app in Java

The thing is : inside a class, I have overrided the OnClick() method because I have to implement a lot of views.

**Now I want to call a function just before OnClick() is called. 
What I mean is, for instance, if the user taps on a button, before OnClick() is called I want one of my methods to be called.**

Does anyone know how to do this ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you just call your other method at the top of `onClick()`?

Comment: The thing is I want inside my method to check if the user has permission to click on the views. If he does have, then I wanted this method to call OnClick. But maybe there is another way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to call a function just before OnClick() is called

You can use a logic inside onClick() like,

```
if(userhaspermission())//your method to check if the user has permission
{
    //your onclick operation code
}
```

Make your checking permission method with **`return type as boolean`**

Answer (score 1):

Implement your custom `OnClickListener` as follows

```
 public abstract class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Do common action

            if(condidtionSatisfied){
                performClick(v);
            }
        }

        public abstract void performClick(View v);
    }
```

**Set `onClickListener` to any component as follows:**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void performClick(View v) {
                 //Execute post click action
            }
        });
```

This will ensure your common code will be called for all the views and it would be much cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `onClick()` method and write your first logic which you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Write your own Listener like Sagar said**

> This logic is quite similar to Sagar's Answers.
>
> Write abstract class as given below

```
    public abstract class OnClick implements View.OnClickListener {

    public void beforeClick(View v) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        beforeClick(v);
        performClick(v);
        afterClick(v);
    }

    public void performClick(View v) {

    }

    public void afterClick(View v) {

    }
    }
```

> NOTE : See in above code it implements View.OnClickListener, so this logic will works for views which extends View super class. If you want above logic for object's which needs Dialog interface onClick then you need to modify it for DialogInterface.OnClickListener.
>
> So you can use above logic as below

```
   //Let say you need it for button with id button

  Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

  button.setOnClickListener(new OnClick() {

        @Override
        public void beforeClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Before", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void performClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "After", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
```

Comment: This logic is not similar to #sagar and not needed. You can simply override onclick and put all the code instead of making separate methods. Both will be same.

Comment: @JyotiJK I appreciate. But what if you have some general logic which should always execute before onClick? In such case user need to write such logic in beforeClick method which is in OnClick abstract class and logic which is differ per view it will be in beforeClick inside of setOnClickListener(new OnClick() { beforeClick(View v) })